# Why does Jetpack Joyride keep refreshing my missions?

Tags: ios, jetpack-joyride

When I leave and reconnect to the game, it keeps refreshing my missions. This becomes quite the problem when I am half-way through one of them but every time I reconnect, I am forced to start all over again.

**Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?**

Answer (score 1):

Some missions are just for the current game.

For example, *Touch 10 red lights **in one game***. The mission will ultimately restart if you do not complete it in that **one game**.

Other missions that do not require you to finish in **one game** will not be reset.

Comment: I know what you mean but every mission on my page keeps resetting every time I close it and open it back up. It doesn't even restart it just completely refreshes to a new mission altogether.